# JQUERY: Close a div if user clicks outside of it

Tags: jquery

I have a hidden div that opens up with a user clicks on the the title (Notifications).  The "subpanel" div is hidden by default, but using jquery it will toggle open/close when a user clicks on the word Notifications.

How can I modify my jquery so that if a user clicks outside of the div that is toggled open (subpanel), this would also trigger the subpanel to close/hide ?

```
<div class="notiftitle" id="notiftitle">
<a href="#" class="alerts">Notifications</a>
 <div class="subpanel">
    <div id="title">New Notifications</div>
    <ul>
      <li>Data</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Switch the "Open" and "Close" state per click then slide up/down (depending on open/close state)
    $(".alerts").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("notiftitleactive");
        $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle(50);
        return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
    });


});
```

Comment: You may better want to use evt.preventDefault() rather than return false: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/javascript-event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need the "outerClick"-event. [ouerClick jQuery plugin by Jon Kassen](http://littleroom.se/playground/outerClick/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event:

```
$(".alerts").blur(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("notiftitleactive");
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle(50);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [mouseout](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) method.

Comment: I dont want it to close when the mouse leaves, only if someone clicks away from it